# Разместить иконку над двумя view (storyboard)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

Всем привет. Нужно сделать иконку поверх двух view с одинаковым видом на всех экранах.

1. Для top view задал equal height view 0.87
2. Для bottom view задал equal height view 0.13

Какие параметры нужно задать для иконки чтобы ее центр был между двумя view?

[image: main.storyboard]
[image: views]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут все довольно просто:

1) Выделите два `view`: иконку и например верхнее `view`

2) Aligne -> Bottom Edgaes (Может быть и top edges или вертикальный/горизонтальный центр, Bottom Edgaes привел как пример)
[image: Aligne -> Bottom Edgaes]

3) Теперь выберите данный констрейнт и укажите, что центр иконки должен соответствовать низу вашего `view`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]